# What is the impact of moving a geyser outside?

Tags: water-heater, energy-efficiency

We have an indoor geyser but are considering moving this outdoor to save space. We live in a Mediterranean climate with a cold winter day being 5°C (41°F) and summer temperatures generally ranging from 20-25°C (68-77°F). I imagine that the inside temperature is about 5°C (9°F) higher inside than outside during a winter day. In summer things are pretty much the same inside vs outside.

Our geyser is the number one electricity consumer in our household. I am wondering, if we move it outside, how would it affect electricity consumption? Any idea how much it would increase?

Comment: I presume you're in the UK? (For those in the US, a geyser is a water heater.)

Comment: How low might the temperature drop in the middle of an unusually cold winter *night*. You probably don't want it to freeze up and burst every other year. There may be local laws about the location of these sort of devices.

Comment: I bet your geyser (never heard that before...) is designed either as indoor-only or able to be placed outdoors. Perhaps if you supplied make and model we could figure out which it is.

Comment: @keshlam I was wondering about getting the ceiling wet every 60-90 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you keshlam. Anyway, it may actually cost less throughout the year. Paint it black (or just dark) or put it in a dark shed in a sunny area to greatly assist heating & heat retention. Air temperature is always lower than Solar Gain, a roof can reach 48C (120F) in 21C (70F) air.

If doing a shed, the year-round setup would be to heavily insulate the shed so it retains as much heat as is generated & that radiates in. If no shed, then a heavy insulation sleeve would be beneficial for the winter. Leading to, if you have an attic, it should go there instead.